# Passing parameters to a JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to make my validation class for my program. I already establish the connection to the MySQL database and I already inserted rows into the table. The table consists of `firstName`, `lastName` and `userID` fields. Now I want to select a specific row on the database through my parameter of my constructor.

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class Validation {

    private PreparedStatement statement;
    private Connection con;
    private String x, y;

    public Validation(String userID) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            statement = con.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT * from employee WHERE  userID = " + "''" + userID);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                x = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.print(x);
                System.out.print(" ");
                y = rs.getString(2);
                System.out.println(y);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem work.

Comment: What problem are you facing??

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should use the [`setString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method to set the `userID`. This both ensures that the statement is formatted properly, and prevents *SQL injection*:

```
statement =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE  userID = ?");
statement.setString(1, userID);
```

There is a nice tutorial on how to use `PreparedStatement`s properly in [the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Note security risk in answer below from @nandkumar-tekale

Answer (score 11):

If you are using prepared statement, you should use it like this:

```
"SELECT * from employee WHERE userID = ?"
```

Then use:

```
statement.setString(1, userID);
```

`?` will be replaced in your query with the user ID passed into `setString` method.

Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) how to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Answer (score 6):

Do something like this, which also prevents [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

```
statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE  userID = ?");
statement.setString(1, userID);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a problem in your query..

```
   statement =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE  userID = "+"''"+userID);
   ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

You are using Prepare Statement.. So you need to set your parameter using `statement.setInt()` or `statement.setString()` depending upon what is the type of your `userId`

**Replace it with: -**

```
   statement =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE  userID = :userId");
   statement.setString(userId, userID);
   ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Or, you can use `?` in place of named value - `:userId`..

```
   statement =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE  userID = ?");
   statement.setString(1, userID);
```

Comment: `statement =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE  userID = :userId");` I don't think this syntax is supported by jdbc. Jdbc doesn't support named parameters, does it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use '?' to set custom parameters in string using PreparedStatments.

```
statement =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE  userID = ?");
statement.setString(1, userID);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

If you directly pass userID in query as you are doing then it may get attacked by **[SQL INJECTION Attack.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**