# How to pass VALUES in MySQL from structure members

Tags: mysql

I want to write the values of structure members into a **MySQL** table. The problem I have is that I wish to read the values of the structure and write the value to the specific column.

```
string assetNumber = EGMSimulatorObj.EGMConfigurationObj.AssetNumber.ToString();
string query = "INSERT INTO egmtable (Asset_Number) VALUES($assetNumber)";
```

With the above, I get the following error:

```
Unknown column '$assetNumber' in 'field list'.
```

How can I use set VALUES from the structure members or from any local variable?

Answer (score 1):

At present MySQL is seeing $assetNumber and so is believing it to be a column name. It has not been replaced with the value.  You may wish instead to concatenate the variable into the string.  I am uncertain which language you are using though.

**PHP**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO egmtable (Asset_Number) VALUES (".$assetNumber.")";
```

**Coldfusion**

```
qryString = "INSERT INTO egmtable (Asset_Number) VALUES ("&assetNumber&")";
```

**Java**

```
string query = "INSERT INTO egmtable (Asset_Number) VALUES("+assetNumber+")";
```

In all these cases though, this is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You would instead be better served using similar to `cfqueryparam` (CF) / `mysqli->bind` (PHP) to allow the language to ensure the value is properly escaped and so ensure your query is safe.  So going down the java route and using [passing parameters to a JDBC PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745186/pass-parameter-from-to-mysql-statement) as a starting point

```
query = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO egmtable (Asset_Number) VALUES( ? )");
query.setString(1, assetNumber);
```

If you are able to specify the language you are using then I can provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
string query = "INSERT INTO egmtable (Asset_Number) VALUES($assetNumber)";
```

with something like

```
string query = "INSERT INTO egmtable (Asset_Number) VALUES("+assetNumber+")";
```

That is, if you are using Java as programming language. Other languages may require other concatenation notation.

Side note: you should maybe use prepared statements for this, for two reasons: security and execution speed.

Comment: I originally thought it might be java, but the dollar notation on the variable threw me out

Comment: oh I see that you answered pretty much the same thing as me. And I was later... so the credit are all yours.

Comment: You actually got the java one up first in fairness - I had to look that one up :)