# JDBC pass parameters to sql query

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have

```
employee(id, name, company, salary);
```

Need to display data for given id

```
public static void Connect(String conString, String username, String password, int id) throws SQLException{
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = null;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, username, password);
            String query = "select * from employee where id = " + id + "" ;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String company = rs.getString("company");
                int salary = rs.getInt("salary");
                System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\tCompany: " + company + "\tSalary: " + salary);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But here we are passing the id directly. How can we pass it like parametrized queries (like how we pass `?` during  `PreparedStatement`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing parameters to a JDBC PreparedStatement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745186/passing-parameters-to-a-jdbc-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in that case your query should be

```
String query = "select * from employee where id = ?";
```

instead of Statement you need to create PreparedStatement

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

and then set your id to the prepared statement

```
preparedStatment.setInt(1, id);
```

finally execute the query

```
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's old post but I would still like to add my answer.

I don't have enough reputation to  comment on @prasad's answer, so I am adding small correction as separate answer. Actually, passing query inside praparedStatement.executeQuery() throws **MySQLSyntaxErrorException** because still it calls Statement.executeQuery instead of PreparedStatement.executeQuery(). And how do I know? I had to spent ample amount of time in figuring out this issue.

So use **PreparedStatement.executeQuery()** instead of **PreparedStament.executeQuery(query)**.