# Pass email as a parameter for SQL query, PostreSQL, JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to pass the email as a parameter for the SELECT SQL query in my JAVA back-end.
As i understood, for some reason it pass only "email_name" from the "email_name@email.com". (Getting this error):

```
Threw a SQLException creating the list of blogs.
ERROR: column "email_name" does not exist
  Position: 174
```

There is an existed rows, which contains "email_name@email.com".
(Why "ERROR: column"? according to query it should look for a value, no?)

**Here is My query:**

```
        String active_user = "email_name@email.com"; //email_name@email.com - example, active_user receive some path variable and on this particular moment(before query execution) contains exactly "email_name@email.com".
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT \n" +
                "  goods.item_title, \n" +
                "  goods.item_descr, \n" +
                "  goods.item_email,\n" +
                "  goods.item_images,\n" +
                "  goods.item_phone, \n" +
                "  goods.item_price \n" +
                "FROM \n" +
                "  public.goods\n" +
                "WHERE goods.owner = "+active_user+"\n" +
                "ORDER BY\n" +
                "  goods.item_id ASC;");
```

So the question is - how to pass full email to query?

Comment: You should look into `PreparedStatement` instead of executing raw SQL. This can lead to SQL injection. It will also solve your problem (being that you miss quotes around `active_user`).

Comment: Awoogah, awoogah. SQL injection detected. Your user with email `bobby@tables.com');DROP TABLE goods;--` just crashed your system. See http://bobby-tables.com/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `String active_user = "'email_name@email.com'";`. with single quotes. Since postgre recognized as column when you use double quotes.

**You should use `PreparedStatement`. this is a [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)**

Answer (score 2):

Very unsafe approach, you should use `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL injection. Here is existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12745238/3961156)