# SQL Query based on user input in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

```
dis = new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
int choice = dis.readInt();
Connection conn = MySqlConnect.ConnectDB();
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select hostname from clients where C_ID=");
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

How can I put choice into the given query?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745186/passing-parameters-to-a-jdbc-preparedstatement

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `pst.setInt` like this:

```
 PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement("Select hostname from clients where C_ID=?");
 pst.setInt(1, choice);
 ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
```