# Java JDBC how to dynamic generate query with multiple conditions in where

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am new to JDBC, currently I am not sure, how to dynamically generate query with multiple conditions in where?

Here is query using JDBC with one condition:

```
SELECT 
    sp.*, se.sepurch_email, issuppno, isstates
FROM supplier sp
LEFT JOIN suppliser_email se ON spsuppno = sesuppno AND spstate = sestate 
LEFT JOIN int_supplier ON spsuppno = issuppno AND islive = 'Y'
WHERE 
   spsuppno = : SUPPLIER_NUMBER_PARAM AND spstate = : SUPPLIER_STATE_CODE_PARAM;
```

Now I have a request with a list of `(SUPPLIER_NUMBER_PARAM, SUPPLIER_STATE_CODE_PARAM)`

How can I convert the query into the format dynamically as below, because I dont know how many in the request list:

```
WHERE 
  (spsuppno = 1000 AND spstate = 'vic') 
  OR 
  (spsuppno = 2000 AND spstate = 'NSW')
```

Many thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like you tried doing anything yourself. The other person may have downvoted for some other reason, but my downvote is definitely because of that.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov how do you know i didn't?? ridiculuos

Comment: @M.Prokhorov sb

Comment: Because you show no attempt.

Comment: You don't have a lot of options. You're going to have to build the query yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to what i used some time ago

```
public List<Book> findAllFiltered(String title, String genre, String author) {
        Connection connection = jdbConnectionWrapper.getConnection();
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM book";
            if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(title) ||
                    !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(genre) ||
                    !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(author)) {
                query = query + " WHERE";
            }

            if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(title)) {
                query = query + " title LIKE '%" + title + "%'";
            }

            if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(genre)) {
                if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(title)) {
                    query = query + " AND";
                }
                query = query + " genre LIKE '%" + genre + "%'";
            }

            if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(author)) {
                if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(title) ||
                        !StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(genre)) {
                    query = query + " AND";
                }
                query = query + " author LIKE '%" + author + "%'";
            }

            System.out.println(query);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

            //some extra code here for retrieveing data
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the article in the link from oracle on JDBC prepare statement
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

There is an example there on how you can make it work

or refer to

[passing parameters to a JDBC PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745186/passing-parameters-to-a-jdbc-preparedstatement)