# Is there a way to pass an argument as a value for insert into a sql table?

Tags: java, sql

I would like to insert mySurname into mysql table as a value (written using java, derby).

Is there a way to do so?

```
public void addPatient(String mySurname){
        try {            
            statement.execute("INSERT INTO patients (id_patient,surname) VALUES(1,mySurname)");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PatientBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters to a JDBC PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745186/passing-parameters-to-a-jdbc-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the short answer to your question is "yes," you can.

A few things here...

First, try to open all the database resources in the same block, or nest blocks with functions.  Second, always close your statements and resources in finally blocks (or with the try-with-resources syntax).  Third, prefer the use of executeUpdate instead of flat execute if you know you'll be inserting values.

Here is a better way to write your example:

```
public void updatePatient(String mySurname) {
   try(conn = yourDataSource.getConnection()) {
      addPatient(mySurname, conn);
   }
}


public void addPatient(String mySurname, Connection con) {
   try(stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO patients (id, surname) VALUES (?, ?)") {
   stmt.setInt(1, 1);
   stmt.setString(2, mySurname);

   int numRowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate();
   Logger.getLogger(PatientBase.class).log(Level.DEBUG, numRowsAffected + " were inserted");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(PatientBase.class).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best practice would be to actually build a PreparedStatement first and then bind the variables, you can check [this link for a tutorial](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4983/Bind-Variables-in-Oracle-and-Java.html#:%7E:text=Bind%20variables%20should%20be%20used,to%20be%20executed%20multiple%20times).