# I got this error " Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '1/1/2000' for column `schooldb`.`student`.`DOB` at row 1"

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch data from my drag and dropped form, but the date entered in the date field can't be accepted by the database.

```java
String s1 = stdid.getText();
String s2 = name.getText();
String s3 = dob.getText();
String s6 = (String) combogender.getSelectedItem();
String s4 = email.getText();
String s7 = txtpassword.getText();
String s5 = contact.getText();

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(cs,user,password);
    st = con.createStatement();
    query = "INSERT INTO student(studentid,Name,DOB,gender,email,password,contact)     values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"',DATE'"+s3+"','"+s6+"','"+s4+"','"+s7+"','"+s5+"')";
    st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: You can't just prepend the string 'Date' to a date string and do an insert. It doesn't work like that. I would use `setDate` properly *in the context of a `PreparedStatement`*. Currently, even if it worked, your code is potentially vulnerable to injection attack

Comment: @g00se Although using prepared statements with parameters should be used here, it technically can work, if the expected syntax of a DATE literal is used, which in the SQL standard is only ISO-8601 format (i.e. `DATE'2000-01-01'` or `DATE '2000-01-01'`). Some DBMSes are more lenient and allow a variety of date syntax in their date literals.

Comment: Your code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection. You should not concatenate values into a query string like this (especially not if they are received from user input!). Please read [Passing parameters to a JDBC PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745186/passing-parameters-to-a-jdbc-preparedstatement) and https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for that. I've never seen that before. It works in MySql with ISO format